# Singleton python generator? Or, pickle a python generator?

Tags: python, singleton, generator, pickle, persistent

I am using the following code, with nested generators, to iterate over a text document and return training examples using `get_train_minibatch()`. I would like to persist (pickle) the generators, so I can get back to the same place in the text document. However, you cannot pickle generators.

- Is there a simple workaround, so that I can save my position and start back where I stopped? Perhaps I can make `get_train_example()` a singleton, so I don't have several generators lying around. Then, I could make a global variable in this module that keeps track of how far along `get_train_example()` is.
- Do you have a better (cleaner) suggestion, to allow me to persist this generator?

[edit: Two more ideas:

- Can I add a member variable/method to the generator, so I can call generator.tell() and find the file location? Because then, the next time I create the generator, I can ask it to seek to that location. **This idea sounds the simplest of everything.**
- Can I create a class and have the file location be a member variable, and then have the generator created within the class and update the file location member variable each time it yields? Because then I can know how far into the file it it.

]

Here is the code:

```
def get_train_example():
    for l in open(HYPERPARAMETERS["TRAIN_SENTENCES"]):
        prevwords = []
        for w in string.split(l):
            w = string.strip(w)
            id = None
            prevwords.append(wordmap.id(w))
            if len(prevwords) >= HYPERPARAMETERS["WINDOW_SIZE"]:
                yield prevwords[-HYPERPARAMETERS["WINDOW_SIZE"]:]

def get_train_minibatch():
    minibatch = []
    for e in get_train_example():
        minibatch.append(e)
        if len(minibatch) >= HYPERPARAMETERS["MINIBATCH SIZE"]:
            assert len(minibatch) == HYPERPARAMETERS["MINIBATCH SIZE"]
            yield minibatch
            minibatch = []
```

Comment: "Pickled Python Generator" would be an excellent name for a band.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code should do more-or-less what you want.  The first class defines something that acts like a file but can be pickled.  (When you unpickle it, it re-opens the file, and seeks to the location where it was when you pickled it).  The second class is an iterator that generates word windows.

```
class PickleableFile(object):
    def __init__(self, filename, mode='rb'):
        self.filename = filename
        self.mode = mode
        self.file = open(filename, mode)
    def __getstate__(self):
        state = dict(filename=self.filename, mode=self.mode,
                     closed=self.file.closed)
        if not self.file.closed:
            state['filepos'] = self.file.tell()
        return state
    def __setstate__(self, state):
        self.filename = state['filename']
        self.mode = state['mode']
        self.file = open(self.filename, self.mode)
        if state['closed']: self.file.close()
        else: self.file.seek(state['filepos'])
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return getattr(self.file, attr)

class WordWindowReader:
    def __init__(self, filenames, window_size):
        self.filenames = filenames
        self.window_size = window_size
        self.filenum = 0
        self.stream = None
        self.filepos = 0
        self.prevwords = []
        self.current_line = []

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def next(self):
        # Read through files until we have a non-empty current line.
        while not self.current_line:
            if self.stream is None:
                if self.filenum >= len(self.filenames):
                    raise StopIteration
                else:
                    self.stream = PickleableFile(self.filenames[self.filenum])
                    self.stream.seek(self.filepos)
                    self.prevwords = []
            line = self.stream.readline()
            self.filepos = self.stream.tell()
            if line == '':
                # End of file.
                self.stream = None
                self.filenum += 1
                self.filepos = 0
            else:
                # Reverse line so we can pop off words.
                self.current_line = line.split()[::-1]

        # Get the first word of the current line, and add it to
        # prevwords.  Truncate prevwords when necessary.
        word = self.current_line.pop()
        self.prevwords.append(word)
        if len(self.prevwords) > self.window_size:
            self.prevwords = self.prevwords[-self.window_size:]

        # If we have enough words, then return a word window;
        # otherwise, go on to the next word.
        if len(self.prevwords) == self.window_size:
            return self.prevwords
        else:
            return self.next()
```

Comment: But then I also have to write ANOTHER class for the minibatch reader, because there are nested generators.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a standard iterator object, it just won't be as convenient as the generator; you need to store the iterator's state on the instace (so that it is pickled), and define a next() function to return the next object:

```
class TrainExampleIterator (object):
    def __init__(self):
        # set up internal state here
        pass
    def next(self):
        # return next item here
        pass
```

The iterator protocol is simple as that, defining the `.next()` method on an object is all you need to pass it to for loops etc.

In Python 3, the iterator protocol uses the `__next__` method instead (somewhat more consistent).

Comment: This is probably the closest you can get to pickling a generator under standard python. Of course, it's not a generator per se, but it will act like one.

Keep in mind that if you're working with files, you'll need to buffer the contents. File objects can't be pickled either.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be an option for you, but Stackless Python (http://stackless.com) *does* allow you to pickle things like functions and generators, under certain conditions. This will work:

In foo.py:

```
def foo():
    with open('foo.txt') as fi:
        buffer = fi.read()
    del fi
    for line in buffer.split('\n'):
        yield line
```

In foo.txt:

```
line1
line2
line3
line4
line5
```

In the interpreter:

```
Python 2.6 Stackless 3.1b3 060516 (python-2.6:66737:66749M, Oct  2 2008, 18:31:31) 
IPython 0.9.1 -- An enhanced Interactive Python.

In [1]: import foo

In [2]: g = foo.foo()

In [3]: g.next()
Out[3]: 'line1'

In [4]: import pickle

In [5]: p = pickle.dumps(g)

In [6]: g2 = pickle.loads(p)

In [7]: g2.next()
Out[7]: 'line2'
```

Some things to note: you *must* buffer the contents of the file, and delete the file object. This means that the contents of the file will be duplicated in the pickle.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider using NLTK's corpus readers:

- http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/api/nltk.corpus.reader-module.html
- http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/corpus.html

-Edward

Comment: StreamBackedCorpusView might be appropriate, but I can't find documentation about how I can save and load the state of these objects.

Answer (score 0):

1. Convert the generator to a class in which the generator code is the `__iter__` method
2. Add `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods to the class, to handling pickling. Remember that you can’t pickle file objects. So `__setstate__` will have to re-open files, as necessary.

I describe this method in more depth, with sample code, [here](http://blog.metaoptimize.com/2009/12/22/why-cant-you-pickle-generators-in-python-workaround-pattern-for-saving-training-state/).

Comment: It is about the same idea, that I offered, just I suggested to use `__call__` instead of `__iter__`. In my not so humble opinion =)

Answer (score -1):

You can try create callable object:

```
class TrainExampleGenerator:

    def __call__(self):
        for l in open(HYPERPARAMETERS["TRAIN_SENTENCES"]):
            prevwords = []
            for w in string.split(l):
                w = string.strip(w)
                id = None
                prevwords.append(wordmap.id(w))
                if len(prevwords) >= HYPERPARAMETERS["WINDOW_SIZE"]:
                    yield prevwords[-HYPERPARAMETERS["WINDOW_SIZE"]:]

get_train_example = TrainExampleGenerator()
```

Now you can turn all state that needs to be saved into object fields and expose them to pickle. This is a basic idea and I hope this helps, but I haven't tried this myself yet.

UPDATE:
Unfortunately, I failed to deliver my idea. Provided example is not complete solution. You see, `TrainExampleGenerator` have no state. You must design this state and make it available for pickling. And `__call__` method should use and modify that state so that to return generator which started from the position determined by object's state. Obviously, generator itself won't be pickle-able. But `TrainExampleGenerator` will be possible to pickle and you'll be able to recreate generator with it *as if* generator itself were pickled.

Comment: This won't help -- when you call get_train_example(), you'll get back an iterator, and you still won't be able to pickle that.  You could pickle the TrainExampleGenerator, but that doesn't store any state.

Comment: To clarify, `__call__` will return a *generator*. No matter what objects are inside the generator's scope, a generator is simply not pickle-able. Once you've activated a function with a `yield`, pickle simply won't talk to you.

Comment: Obviously generator returned by `__call__` is not pickle-able and I haven't claimed the opposite. But `TrainExampleGenerator` itself (its state) can be made pickle-able. And after unpickling it, its `__call__` could return generator that starts from saved position. How to design this pickle-able state is another question, but I'm pretty sure that it's possible.