# Why can't generators be pickled?

Tags: python, generator, pickle, python-stackless

Python's pickle (I'm talking standard Python 2.5/2.6/2.7 here) cannot pickle locks, file objects etc.

It also cannot pickle generators and lambda expressions (or any other anonymous code), because the pickle really only stores name references.

In case of locks and OS-dependent features, the reason *why* you cannot pickle them is obvious and makes sense.

But **why can't you pickle generators?**

---

*Note*: just for clarity -- I'm interested in the fundamental reason (or assumptions and choices that went into that design decision) *why*, not in "because it gives you a Pickle error".

I realize the question's a bit wide-aimed, so here's a rule of thumb of whether your answered it: "If these assumptions were raised, or the type of allowed generator somehow more restricted, would pickling generators work again?"

Comment: When would it make sense to pickle a generator?

Comment: @NullUser: It's not too hard to imagine; You're iterating through one and you want to stop your program and later resume where you left off later.

Comment: ...or resume at the same time, but from a different program (=serializing is also used in network transmission)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is lots of information about this available. For the "official word" on the issue, read the [(closed) Python bugtracker issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue1092962).

The core reasoning, by one of the people who made the decision, is detailed on [this blog](http://peadrop.com/blog/2009/12/29/why-you-cannot-pickle-generators/):

> Since a generator is essentially a souped-up function, we would need to save its bytecode, which is not guarantee to be backward-compatible between Python’s versions, and its frame, which holds the state of the generator such as local variables, closures and the instruction pointer. And this latter is rather cumbersome to accomplish, since it basically requires to make the whole interpreter picklable. So, any support for pickling generators would require a large number of changes to CPython’s core.
>
> Now if an object unsupported by pickle (e.g., a file handle, a socket, a database connection, etc) occurs in the local variables of a generator, then that generator could not be pickled automatically, regardless of any pickle support for generators we might implement. So in that case, you would still need to provide custom `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods. This problem renders any pickling support for generators rather limited.

And two suggested workarounds are mentioned:

> Anyway, if you need for a such feature, then look into Stackless Python which does all the above. And since Stackless’s interpreter is picklable, you also get process migration for free. This means you can interrupt a tasklet (the name for Stackless’s green threads), pickle it, send the pickle to a another machine, unpickle it, resume the tasklet, and voilà you’ve just migrated a process. This is freaking cool feature!
>
> But in my humble opinion, the best solution to this problem to the rewrite the generators as simple iterators (i.e., one with a `__next__` method). Iterators are easy and efficient space-wise to pickle because their state is explicit. You would still need to handle objects representing some external state explicitly however; you cannot get around this.

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks. I found "generator_tools", a pure Python package that claims to do this. I can't get it to work though, so I guess you (and Alexandre) are right...

Comment: That package is mentioned on http://metaoptimize.com/blog/2009/12/22/why-cant-you-pickle-generators-in-python-workaround-pattern-for-saving-training-state/ which also has another workaround pattern.

Comment: How can you provide an answer and vote "close" at the same time? Now I'm curiously waiting for the "debate, arguments and extended discussion" :-)

Comment: I misread your question at first and you can't take back a close vote. I was also the first one who voted to re-open.

Comment: Kay, the author of "generator_tools", says it works fine with some limitations, for Python 2.5. Unfortunately, with the question closed, we'll probably never hear the full account :( So I'm accepting your answer, though my curiosity is not fully satisfied.

Answer (score 27):

You actually can, depending on the implementation. [PyPy](http://pypy.org) and [Stackless Python](http://stackless.com) both allow this (to some degree anyway):

```
Python 2.7.1 (dcae7aed462b, Aug 17 2011, 09:46:15)
[PyPy 1.6.0 with GCC 4.0.1] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
And now for something completely different: ``Not your usual analyses.''
>>>> import pickle
>>>> gen = (x for x in range(100))
>>>> next(gen)
0
>>>> pickled = pickle.dumps(gen)
>>>> next(pickle.loads(pickled))
1
```

In CPython it's also possible to create an [iterator object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1939015/singleton-python-generator-or-pickle-a-python-generator/1939493#1939493) to simulate a pickable generator.

Comment: @Radim it answered _my_ question.