# Why can't python module dill pickle the generator function?

Tags: python, generator, pickle, dill

Dill module is awesome, it can pickle the entire python interpretor global state. But Dill cannot pickle generators. I know it is not supported. But i would like to know the technical reason given that it can pickle python functions?

Comment: I'm not sure there is a technical reason; from the web page, "Dill cannot yet pickle these standard types: - frame, generator, traceback" implies they just haven't supported it yet. Maybe there is a technical reason that makes it tricky to do so.

Comment: I am curious why it is tricky? given that dill can pickle stateful functions and objects.

Comment: I have no idea; I'm just assuming that's the case if it's one of the last things they *don't* support yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is covered in dill's issue tracker, [issue #10 (pickle iterators)](https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/10), which says that it's not easily done--for reference it points both to [an existing Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7180424/2386185) and to Python's issue tracker, particularly to an enhancement request titled [Make Generators Pickle-able](http://bugs.python.org/issue1092962), which was rejected.

Comment: Thx for the answer.  Bummer though.

Comment: Yeah. At least they didn't close the door completely, it's just not a priority (and they want someone to come up with a *good* implementation before they'll consider it)... So who knows, maybe it'll happen someday :)