# Persist generator object into some file type with python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, generator, pickle

I have a generator object obtained by sklearn 
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.GradientBoostingClassifier.html

```
df_fit = clf.fit(df_training, df_label.values.ravel())
generator=clf.staged_decision_function(df_training)
```

However, I wish to persist the Generator object in generator variable in some file type so I can retrieve them by reading the file back and save into a variable. I had tried using pickle with

```
pickle.dumps(generator)
```

The approach failed and from Google I learnt that we cannot serialize generator object in pickle. I am trying to save it in txt but I don't think it is the proper way to do. Any idea?

Comment: The only way to preserve a Python object is to serialize it. So, you just answered your question.

Comment: Is there a way you can extract the state from the generator (and then have a mechanism to set the exact same state again)? `pickle` relies on `__getstate__` and `__setstate__` methods, which are probably not implemented for generators.

Comment: @DYZ Except for generators... https://stackoverflow.com/a/7180424/4293417

Comment: I think I solved it with convert the generator into list first. ... WIll get back to you after I try it. Thank you for the reply

Comment: @MervynLee If you want to pickle a generator, you can use `dill`. Install it first with `pip install dill`. Then use `dill.dump(...)`.

Comment: One workaround here is that maybe you can pickle the `clf` with it and call the `staged_decision_function()` again when loading. Scikit-learn docs recommend using [joblib for its object](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html).