# Pickle functools wrapper error: can't pickle functools.KeyWrapper objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, pickle, sortedlist, functools

I am trying to pickle a SortedListWithKey for which I am using cmp_to_key() from functools to convert a comparison function to a key function. 
However, the cmp_to_key() seems to make my object unpickable and I get the following error: TypeError: can't pickle functools.KeyWrapper objects

How can I fix it? This is a code sample to reproduce the error:

```
import pickle
from functools import cmp_to_key
from sortedcontainers import SortedListWithKey

def order_fun(a, b):
    if abs(a[0]-b[0]) < 1e-8:
        return 0
    elif a[0]-b[0] > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(SortedListWithKey([[1,2], [3,4]], key=cmp_to_key(order_fun))))
```

Thanks!

Note: The pickling works fine without using the cmp_to_key() function, but I need it since my function is not a key function.

Comment: can generators be pickled? maybe try: `list(SortedListWithKey(...))` ? see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7180212/why-cant-generators-be-pickled#7180424 by using the `key` kwarg i think it turns it into a generator?

Comment: A very old question, not every objects can be pickled. Try converting to some basic objects.

Comment: You can't pickle a function (of any kind). There's an module named [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill/0.2.7.1) that ought to be able to do it, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem seems to be that [cmp_tp_key](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.cmp_to_key) is [now written in C](https://bugs.python.org/issue11707), and the class it returns is neither pickleable nor subclassable. However, the original pure python version is [still maintained in the source](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Lib/functools.py#L211), and is very simple. When this is used with your example, it works correctly. Of course, the obvious downside is that the pure python version is slower - but [the difference is not huge](https://bugs.python.org/issue11707#msg132969).

Here is a working version of your example:

```
import pickle
from sortedcontainers import SortedListWithKey

def order_fun(a, b):
    if abs(a[0]-b[0]) < 1e-8:
        return 0
    elif a[0]-b[0] > 0:
        return 1
    else:
        return -1

class KeyFunc(object):
    __slots__ = ['obj']
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self.obj = obj
    def __lt__(self, other):
        return order_fun(self.obj, other.obj) < 0
    def __gt__(self, other):
        return order_fun(self.obj, other.obj) > 0
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return order_fun(self.obj, other.obj) == 0
    def __le__(self, other):
        return order_fun(self.obj, other.obj) <= 0
    def __ge__(self, other):
        return order_fun(self.obj, other.obj) >= 0
    __hash__ = None

sl = SortedListWithKey([[1,2], [3,4]], key=KeyFunc)

print(sl)

print(pickle.loads(pickle.dumps(sl)))
```

Output:

```
SortedListWithKey([[1, 2], [3, 4]], key=<class '__main__.KeyFunc'>)
SortedListWithKey([[1, 2], [3, 4]], key=<class '__main__.KeyFunc'>)
```